# Android appbarlayout elevation appears in status bar

Tags: android, appbar, android-appbarlayout, android-elevation

How do I get rid of the elevation in the status bar? If I set in AppbarLayout the app:elevation to 0dp the elevation doesn't appear anymore in status bar but also not below the AppbarLayout.

How do I just get the elevation under the AppbarLayout?

Here's a screenshot of what I mean: [puush link](http://puu.sh/lmYpn/0141c962ce.jpg), notice the shadow in the status bar :(

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the Theme of your activity?

Comment: Do you have draw behing statusbar flag?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean @NikolaDespotoski

Comment: Amazed that so few people notice this glaring bug!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Our concern is about shadow of `AppBarLayout` visible when status bar is transparent. Having an opaque status bar is not viable at all times. This happens on Lollipop & above only because of dynamic shadow rendering. On Marshmallow the wrong shadow looks even worse.

**Best solution**

Your root layout should have `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` at all times, otherwise your UI will not draw behind status bar.

Now wrap the `AppBarLayout` inside another `CoordinatorLayout` which has `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"`. This will prevent the shadow from overflowing into statusbar

---

**Other workarounds** (not recommended)

In your Style remove the statusBarColor:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

So your theme would be:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
</style>
```

*Also you can simply make app:elevation="0dp" on appbarlayout, but that removes the shadow on bottom also.*

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works.Here is a sample for reference for everyone else:  https://gist.github.com/sahilshekhawat/00d24fb217f74f06fca27d133cb10d1a