# How to remove the shadow above the app bar?

Tags: java, android, xml, statusbar, appbar

I'd like to make the status bar transparent by adding `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>` to v21/styles.xml on `style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar"` but I keep getting a shadow above the app bar, is it possible to remove it?

EDIT:
Ok I think the solution is to move the app bar occupying the status bar space and extending the app bar of an additional dp to match it size so my question is, is it possible to move or extend the app bar height upwards?

activity_search.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.AppBarOverlay">

     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
          android:id="@+id/toolbar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
          app:popupTheme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_search"/>
```

[image]

Comment: above or below? if above then its your colorPrimaryDark

Comment: @Bhargav above the app bar, which is visible on the status bar.

Comment: Yes that is your colorPrimaryDark attribute, but if you were to draw a navigation drawer under it, it would should the status bar as transparent

Comment: @Bhargav yup, the reason why I wanted to add <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item> is because I'll implement a nav drawer next.

Comment: yes when the nav drawer goes under it, you will notice that status bar is still transparent, so don't worry about this and just continue coding

Comment: @Bhargav but I feel like having a shadow above the app bar isn't visually correct :/

Comment: I think that shadow is not the shadow of the app bar but of the status bar, even if you were to make elevation 0dp to the appbar there would still be that shadow there is my guess

Comment: @Bhargav I believe it is the shadow of the app bar and I just tried to make its elevation=0dp, all of its shadow are gone but I'm thinking if it's possible to only remove the above part of its shadow and not the below one

Comment: post code of that layout here please

Comment: Did you try to remove the _app:popupTheme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.PopupOverlay"_  ? Maybe the problem is coming from the style.

Comment: @JJ86 nope, I believe it's not coming from the style as this happens everytime I start a new default project in Android Studio.

Comment: @brettbrdls if you say so; can you show us your _MyMaterialTheme_ theme xml as well?

Comment: The shadow is coming from the AppBarLayout , specifically from the `app:elevation` attribute. It can be set to 0, but this obviously removes the bottom shadow too.

Comment: @mvai yes, that's the problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe this question is pointing to same problem
[Android appbarlayout elevation appears in status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33726318/android-appbarlayout-elevation-appears-in-status-bar)

> Possible solutions:

Your root layout should have `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` at all times, otherwise your UI will not draw behind status bar.

Now wrap the `AppBarLayout` inside another `CoordinatorLayout` which has

`android:fitsSystemWindows="false"`.

**This will prevent the shadow from overflowing into statusbar.**

Comment: @brettbrdls, I don't think this solution works now in AppCompat v24.0.0

Comment: What if my root layout is the CoordinatorLayout? I tried wrapping it in another layout but in that case the status bar is white while it should be red (colorPrimaryDark)

Comment: Does not matter what your root layout is. Wrap your AppBarLayout in a CoordinatorLayout and set android:fitsSystemWindows="false". CoordinatorLayout is designed to have special interaction with appcompat elements, so it automagically takes care of many things

Comment: Problem is, wrapping your AppBarLayout in another CoordinatorLayout breaks ScrollingViewBehavior, so a RecyclerView now covers the appbar and everything. In my particular case, I'm trying to get a recyclerview to go behind a translucent navigation bar without the status bar looking like crap, without the status bar going over the top of the navigation drawer, etc. So far everything I've tried breaks at least one of those.

Answer (score 5):

Add elevation 0dp to **AppBarLayout**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:elevation="0dp">
```

Comment: But is it possible to only remove the shadow above the app bar and not the below part?

Answer (score 5):

Call below method in the **onCreate** of your activity with the desired status bar color.

```
public void changeStatusBarColor(String hexColor)
  {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#AD2525"));
    }
 }
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.bharath.myapplication.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#AD2525"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <!--
    Other views
    -->

</RelativeLayout></android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[**Result**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjlFD.png)

Comment: Only answer that works. Other suggesting app:elevation="0dp" defeats the object. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                 />

 </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also add padding on app bar based on status bar height:

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(binding.root) { _, insets ->
        val statusBarInsets = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars())
        val bottomBarInsets = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars())
        binding.appBarLayout.setPadding(0, statusBarInsets.top, 0, 0)
        binding.root.setPadding(0, 0, 0, bottomBarInsets.bottom)
        insets
    }
```

You can put this in your `onCreateView()` or `onViewCreated()` methods.
Remember to remove `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from your layout, because you're manually setting the padding to the views, and the insets must remains like it's a full screen fragment.

Answer (score 0):

*put this line in the `oncreate()` method of activity file of which activity you want to remove the elevation of the action bar*

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```